# How is data represented in postgresql internally

Tags: postgresql

I've been using MongoDB and I know that it uses the Bson specification to serialize data into bytes, uses (and stores) it. This data is then transmitted to the client where the client's driver de-serializes it into the types native to the program (eg: document -> python dict). Lately I've been having a lot of this (de)serialization overhead and started to look into other dbs.

Consider my typical use case: issue a db.query(SOME_QUERY), iterate over the cursor, pass them to one or more functions, take the result and write it back. so in MongoDB with the python driver, the cursor is a de-serialized python dict containing other python objects.

I'm wondering how this takes place in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has its own protocol. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol.html) tells you how that works. Data types have a “send” and “receive” function that – as you call it – serialize and deserialize the data for transfer (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xtypes.html) for details). You will have to read the PostgreSQL source to find the the implementation for each data type.